# How do I round to one place but force extra 0 so it looks like normal price?

Tags: javascript

In JS How do I round to one place but force extra 0 so it looks like normal price?

There are many answers on the topic but what I want to achieve is to get rid of the pennies/cents last digit.
So for example instead of 15.98 I can show 16.00 or instead of 14.49 I can show 14.50.

The below rounds to one place but how do I force to show extra zero?

```
c = Math.round(c_ft*10,2)/10
form.ans.value=c
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `toFixed` method to format the number into a string:

```
form.ans.value = (Math.round(c_ft * 10) / 10).toFixed(2);
```